# Performing Same Action Multiple Times on Single File

Tags: animation, action, photoshop

Ok guys, my question is can you batch perform an action a set number of times on a single file?

I have a circle and I want a 100 frames of it animating up to a large circle. Couldn't figure out how to do this in photoshop... at least not automatically without having to play and action and save it myself every time.

I went to flash and did the animation and saved as a PNG sequence. This, however, gave me 100 files that were all the same pixel dimensions. They were what I wanted, but the smallest circle was the same dimension (image size wise) as the largest circle.

Maybe you have a better solution for my problem though. Basically I want 100 frames of a circle animating up, with each image only being the size of the circle itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you resolute the work area same as the size of circle by defining the size of work area.